# Open a pkcs8 file key without use OPENSSL

Tags: java, openssl, private-key, pem, pkcs#8

I'm trying to open a pkcs8 KEY file and I have found some procedures that allow me to generate a PEM file using the OPENSSL library and then generate the PrivateKey from it. 
Unfortunately I want to open the KEY without manipulate the file previously.
Is this possible?

Comment: you want to open keystore file(private key)?

Comment: http://juliusdavies.ca/commons-ssl/pkcs8.html

Answer (score 0):

In [this Web page](http://uetiko-developer.blogspot.mx/2010/02/como-obtener-el-sello-digital-con-java.html) I found the solution. It uses one library that Konstantin mentioned; It worked with the *not-yet-commons-ssl-0.3.11.jar*.

```
byte[] clavePrivada = getBytes(archivoClavePrivada); 
PKCS8Key pkcs8 = new PKCS8Key(clavePrivada, password.toCharArray()); 
PrivateKey pk = pkcs8.getPrivateKey();
```

It uses the method getBytes()

```
private byte[] getBytes(InputStream is) { 
  int totalBytes = 714; 
  byte[] buffer = null; 
  try { 
    buffer = new byte[totalBytes]; 
    is.read(buffer, 0, totalBytes); 
    is.close(); 
  } catch (IOException e) { 
    e.printStackTrace(); 
  } 
  return buffer; 
}
```